# How to keep original hover color when changing link color?

Tags: css

When you give a color to link, it automatically applies this color also to the hover state. Which requires me to specify a hover color every time I want to change the color of a link. I would like to know if there is a way to change link color and keep the original hover color?

Comment: I can't find the link now, but the order of the CSS rules is important. Specify the `a:hover` rule after `a:visited`. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Suppose that there are global rules: blue color for link, and red color for hover. In some divs I want links to have green color. Once I change the color to green, the hover color (red) is removed. I must specify the red hover color again. I need a way to avoid this repeated code. I will add an example

Comment: You want to have a global :hover color for links with different colors?

Comment: I want that link color won't override hover color (which is my situation currently). I'm trying to create a simplified test case, but for some reason it works differently than what I'm experiencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by making the default global `a:hover` more specific than the colored links.

Consider the following example:

```css
a { color: blue }
a:hover { color: red; }

a.color1 { color:green; }
a.color2 { color:orange; }
a.color3 { color:purple; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Default</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="color1">Green Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="color2">Orange Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="color3">Purple Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The hover colors will not be the default red because adding `a.classname` is more specific than `a`

You can solve this by having the classes without the `a` prefix, like this:

```css
a { color: blue }
a:hover { color: red; }

.color1 { color:green; }
.color2 { color:orange; }
.color3 { color:purple; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Default</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="color1">Green Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="color2">Orange Link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="color3">Purple Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Otherwise, you can apply `!important` to the `a:hover` color, like so `a:hover { color: red !important; }` However, this is NOT recommended and should be avoided if possible.